# opkg_conf_parse_file: /etc/opkg/base-feed.conf:1: Ignoring invalid line: `scr/gz base http://192.168.1.X/all'

Tags: beagleboard, opkg

I am updating my system with opkg. and I have this answer

> opkg_conf_parse_file: /etc/opkg/base-feed.conf:1: Ignoring invalid
>   line: `scr/gz base http://192.168.1.X/all'

I don't know why this.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

You put: **scr**/gz base http://192.168.1.X/all'

It should be **src**/gz base http://192.168.1.X/all'